# Redirect program ouput to screen and file simultaneously

Tags: command-line, redirect, tee

I have a Python script. I want to save its result while it outputs something in the terminal. I tried

```bsh
python program.py 2>&1 | tee output.txt
```

However, it seems only after the program finishes, it will print all stuff on the screen. While it's running, there is no output. It really bothers me as I want to know the progress while running the program. Are there any ways to output to screen and file simultaneously?

---

Update Nov 13, 2019

Thanks for the help @egmont. Anyone who's encountering the same problem can try the following commands. It will output on the screen and write to the file simultaneously.

```bsh
stdbuf -oL python program.py 2>&1 | tee ouput.txt
```

Comment: Does your program write out it's progress as this `2>&1` only prints the errors?

Comment: If I just run `python program.py 2>&1`, it will have the progress output and python print function. However, after being redirected, nothing output on the screen. @George

Comment: your program should do that from my own tests!

Comment: try use `sys.stdout.flush()` after you print stuff. (`sys.stderr.flush()` after print to stderr)

Comment: Try prefixing the `python` command with the `stdbuf -oL` wrapper.

Comment: It works well. Thanks @egmont

Comment: You could also look into `script`.

Answer (score 2):

I was experiencing the same problem ("anything" that involved manipulating `stdout` - such as `nohup`, backgrounding (`&`) or redirection). Interestingly for me, `stdbuf -oL` didn't solve the problem. But it turns out that both Python 2 and 3 (from which subversions, I don't know, sorry), support a `-u` option which makes `stdout` and `stderr` unbuffered. See https://www.commandlinux.com/man-page/man1/python2.7.1.html.

I've just noticed (according to that man page) that in Python 2.7 `stdin` is also made unbuffered, whereas the man page for Python 3 (3.10 for me) specifically says `"This option has no effect on the stdin stream."`

So, the OP's original command would become:

```
python -u program.py 2>&1 | tee output.txt
```

I then get the behaviour I would expect with PHP / awk / etc.

As the OP asked for "Are there any ways to output to screen and file simultaneously?", this "solution" relies on `tee` which the OP had already deduced - it just needs the `python -u` to give more familiar behaviour.